# complex query joining multiple tables with aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate

I have the following db structure: [image: db design]

Channels and packages table have many to many relations by channel_package table.

User can purchase packages or channels separately which is stored in purchases table. So when a user purchases a channel channel_id is stored as product_id and cat_id=2 and when a package is purchased, package_id is stored as product_id and cat_id=1.

What I want to get is list of channels having maximum expiry for a particular user.

If the purchases table would only store channels it would have been easy like

```
SELECT 
    p.id,c.name,
    max(p.expiry) 
FROM 
    purchases as p 
    LEFT JOIN channels as c 
        on c.id=p.product_id 
WHERE 
    cat_id = 2 
GROUP by c.id
```

So how can i get the same result considering the packages (packages contains channels, if the channel contained in the package has more expiry? The package's expiry should be displayed as max(expiry).

Comment: Is this a [_Groupwise max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following solution. Note that in your question you group by the `id` field in the `purchases` table, but that won't be possible because a single channel might be included in multiple purchases and if you group by `id` then you won't find the maximum across all purchases, you'll just get the maximum for each single purchase (which is really not a maximum at all).

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.id As channel_id, u.name As channel_name,
    max(u.expiry) As Expires
FROM (
    SELECT p.user_id, c.id, c.name, p.expiry
    FROM purchases As p
    JOIN channel_package As cp ON p.product_id = cp.package_id
    JOIN channels As c ON cp.channel_id = c.id
    WHERE p.cat = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.user_id, c.id, c.name, p.expiry
    FROM purchases As p
    JOIN channels As c On p.product_id = c.id
    WHERE p.cat = 2) As u 
GROUP by u.user_id, u.id, u.name;
```

Comment: i have group by channel id, is it necessary to group by 3 cols, i think grouping by u.channel_id works for a particular user

Comment: Your question said that you want the results by user so I included the `user_id`. In this case, since `channels.name` is functionally dependent on `channels.id` it would be permissible to omit it from the `GROUP BY` but some consider that non-best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Check the result here: http://rextester.com/RQKTP46266

I made it in postgresql, but I think its the same for mysql.

This is the structure used:

```
create temp table ch (cid int, name text);
create temp table pk (pid int, name text);
create temp table pkch (id int, pid int, cid int);
create temp table pu (id int, userid int, prid int, cat int, expiry date);

insert into ch values (1, 'channel 1');
insert into ch values (2, 'channel 2');
insert into ch values (3, 'channel 3');
insert into ch values (4, 'channel 4');
insert into ch values (5, 'channel 5');

insert into pk values (1, 'pack 1');

insert into pkch values (1, 1, 1);
insert into pkch values (2, 1, 2);
insert into pkch values (3, 1, 3);

insert into pu values (1, 10, 1, 1, '2016-05-01');
insert into pu values (2, 10, 2, 2, '2016-04-01');
insert into pu values (3, 10, 3, 2, '2016-04-01');
```

First you should expand channels included in purchased packages, and UNION with the single channels.

The next step is easy, select max(expiry) and goup it by channel.

```
select userid, channel_id, max(expiry)
from
(
    select pu.id, pu.userid, pkch.cid as channel_id, pu.expiry
    from pu
        join pkch on pu.prid = pkch.pid and pu.cat = 1
    where pu.userid = 10
    UNION
    select pu.id, pu.userid, pu.prid as channel_id, expiry
    from pu
    where pu.userid = 10 and pu.cat = 2
) a
group by userid, channel_id
```